# Change session.telephone.dnis value in VXML application?

Tags: ivr, vxml, avaya

I'm working on an Avaya IVR with a Nuance recognizer and TTS engine.  Our application determines call destination information by receiving the DNIS data from the PBX, via a "custom" Avaya variable that describes the call:

```
<script>
  dnis = session.telephone.dnis;
</script>
```

Does anyone know a mechanism by which I can change the dnis value within the session?  When I attempt to change it using the VXML assignment statement, I crash:

```
<assign name="session.telephone.dnis" expr="chosen_dnis"/>
```

It's not super important, but would make things a bit easier for us.

Thanks!
IVR Avenger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

session variables are read-only according to the spec, so you might need to find a different way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks!  Is the spec publicly-available, or is this something that I'd have to go through my Avaya support folks in order to retrieve?

Comment: VoiceXML 1.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml/
VoiceXML 2.0: http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml20/
VoiceXML 2.1: http://www.w3.org/TR/voicexml21/

Answer (score 1):

When you transfer the call, you can use the aai attribute, or you can programatically set the aai, and further along in the call apps can retrieve the aai info and use it (via cti, ccxml, vxml).

Which Avaya product IVR product?  Voice Portal, IR?  Using Dialog Designer?